# Sxhkd not recognising percent key (bspwm)

Tags: linux, window-manager, key-binding

So I want to create a keybinding using my sxhkd that functions like the binding to create panes in tmux.

I have created bindings before so I know that I can use `xev` to print out key names, here is the output when pressing `%` then `"` :

> KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8068709, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8069165, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 14 (keysym 0x25, percent), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (25) "%"
>       XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (25) "%"
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8069236, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 14 (keysym 0x25, percent), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (25) "%"
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8069615, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8090326, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x0, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8090442, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 48 (keysym 0x22, quotedbl), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) """
>       XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) """
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8090593, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 48 (keysym 0x22, quotedbl), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (22) """
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
>       root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 8090652, (324,604), root:(325,624),
>       state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

So in my `~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` I have put:

```
super + percent
    bspc window -p right && urxvt
super + quotedbl 
    bspc window -p down && urxvt
```

Now when I restart sxhkd and press `super + %` keys nothing happens, but the other binding works perfectly.

- Why is sxhkd not recognising the percent key?
- Does sxhkd identify the percent key as a different name from the one given by xev?

---

**Edit:** I did some more searching in the sxhkd git repo and found the file which stores the keysym numbers for each key.

In `parse.c`:

```
{"percent"                     , 0x0025}
```

I tried changing it to `0x25` and recompiling but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after alot of testing I have come up with some solutions of my own.

**It turns out the percent key is recognised just fine but just doesnt work together with the super key**

Option 1) Add `@` infront of the key

```
 @super + percent
     bspc window -p right && urxvt
```

This works but only functions after you release a key

Option 2) Replace `super` with any other key

I decided to go with option 2 and replace `super` with `ctrl`

```
ctrl + {percent,quotedbl}
    bspc window -p {right,down} && urxvt
```